# Relative density plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, density-function, relative-distribution

I have a dataset with two classes, A and B, and an independent variable x. Class B is a minority class with only 1% of the observations, which tend to occur with small values of x. I am interested in the relative densities for the classes, which I would like to visualize in R.

In my imagination, I would use `plot(density(data[cl=="A"]$x)/density(data$x))`, but R doesn't allow division of densities. How should I do this?

Comment: This can easily be done by making sure (beforehand) that the two density vectors are estimated at the same set of values. But you are likely to be surprised by the results: densities will approach or equal zero, making the relative densities you are attempting to compute blow up.  Consider alternative strategies instead.

Comment: `plot(table(cut(data[cl=="A"]$x))/table(cut(data$x)))` almost does the trick, but because the densities are low I'd like some smoothing. `density` seems perfect for that.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure I understand what you mean with estimating them at the same set of values. Could you give an example? Thank you for the note about zero densities, though, that seems sensible.

Comment: Many `R` functions to compute densities and the like start with (or estimate) a range and slice that range into a fixed set of values at equal intervals. You need to make sure the same set of values is used in your two separate calls to `density`. Its manual page tells you what arguments to supply to assure this (`from`, `to`, and `n`).

Comment: @whuber I didn't realize I could access the individual points through `$x` and `$y`. Things make sense now. Unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to +1 your comments, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining your own code with whuber's suggestions (but please bear in mind his warning), something like this might do the trick (untested):

```
xmin<-min(data$x)
xmax<-max(data$x)
n<-1000
Adens<-density(data[cl=="A"]$x), from=xmin, to=xmax, n=n)
Totdens<-density(data$x, from=xmin, to=xmax, n=n)

# Because each density by default has a total area of 1, rescale the y-values of Adens 
# such that its area represents the actual proportion of the A-class. Then, plot the
# ratio between both densities.
Aprop <- length(data[cl=="A"]$x)/length(data$x)
plot(Adens$x, Aprop*Adens$y/Totdens$y, type="l")
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Note: I haven't made any attempt at ruling out zero (smoothed) densities, but that should not be a problem now...

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that densities were internally represented as (x,y)-series. That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: The `Adens` `y`-values still need to be scaled, though. See my edit.